# /dev/urandom range

Tags: python, linux, random, cryptography

I need to generate some token that can only take on a range of characters, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

I'm trying to work with `binascii.b2a_base64(os.urandom(64))`, which has other characters such as + and are causing problems.

What's the range of `/dev/urandom` (i'm on linux) so that I can just map the output integers to a value uniformly myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It generates bytes, so 0x00 to 0xFF inclusive.

Comment: Okay. I ran the test, but I just want to make sure. Now I have to uniformly fit 62 characters into 256 numbers..

Comment: I'd restrict the range further, to get a lower LCM between the number of characters and 256.

Comment: I have this: http://ideone.com/I2GbH  i guess using b2a_base64 and i can just strip out the + and = could also work..

Comment: @owlstead, is what i have above a good way to do it? I'm fairly certain it's the same thing as he has described.

Comment: @ultimatebuster Imagine a string consisting only of + signs... What Adam described is pretty much what is done in e.g. Java classes. I'm not a (full) expert on RNG's, but I think that one is OK.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/urandom` simply supplies random bytes. Every byte you read is in the range `0` to `255`, hopefully uniformly distributed.

A simple approach to dealing with your current problem is to filter out the `+` and `=` characters. In shell it'd be `... | tr -d += | ...`. I don't know the most Pythonic approach, but this appears to work:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\+|=', '', "abcdef+=")
'abcdef'
```